# How to calculate shipping cost by weight?

Tags: java, magento, e-commerce

I want to calculate shipping charge based on product weight. Initially i have two fields, one for selecting country and another for entering weight. Based on these two fields i need to display shipping charge for different shipping methods. If anyone knows the formula to calculate shipping charge based on weight please help me.

Comment: That's a problem concerning business logic, different carriers might have different ways of calculating it.

Comment: Is there any generic formula to calculate shipping charge?

Answer (score 0):

Shipping charge = (cost per kilo/pounds * total weight) * (cost per km/miles * total distance)

You should estimate how much will cost to your company to transport X quantity of products depending on the transport system (truck, ship, plane), the combustible, possible taxes, etc.

Comment: This question is more about business than programming. XD

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to have the weight and destination. You also need to take into account dimensions and number of packages and plenty of other factors like port terminal fees, bill of lading fees, insurance fees, etc.

Ocean freight B2B shippings are often door-to-pier. You ship from your warehouse to a destination port and the customer collects the items there because it is cumbersome to arrange ground transport on foreign countries. Therefore, there is usually a cost in weight × distance by truck plus a price per full container or weight/size + num packages if not sending a full container.

For small items probably you are better off with a flat rate per item and country depending on whether it's ground or air freight. For larger shippings, best connect to an API like the one of UPS or iContainers because the prices are sensitive to cost of fuel and ship departure dates.

Last, for Magento there are several plug-ins available to compute shipping cost. Just Google them :)